# Parse socket message in Python

Tags: python, string, sockets, string-parsing

I made in python a little server that listen on port 4444,when i connect with telnet it's all fine,i can send message and the server display the message correctly.
I have only one problem:
When i try to "parse" the telnet message,I can't do it correctly.
Infact with the If output=="screenshot" i want if the message i sent is "screenshot",the server print on the console a message.
This don't work.
This is my source,i am new to Python and network programming.
Thanks in advance
** EVEN IF I USE == IN THE IF STATEMENT IS THE SAME**
Coogle

**SOURCE**

```
import head
print("SockShot Server Starting\n")
sock=head.Server("localhost",4444)
print("Server STARTED")
while True:
    sock.s.listen(1)
    conn,addr=sock.s.accept()
    print("Connessione stabilita con : {0}:{1} \n".format(addr[0],str(addr[1])))
    conn.send("Benvenuto \n".encode())
    sock.ricevi(conn)
```

**HEAD.py**

```
import socket
import sys
class Server:
    server=""
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self,server,porta):
        self.server=server
        try:
            self.s.bind((server,porta))
            print("Server binding complete \n")
        except:
            print("Binding server incomplete")
            sys.exit(2)

    def ricevi(self,socket):
        result=socket.recv(1024)
        while len(result)>0:
            try:
                print(result.decode())
                result=socket.recv(1024)
                self._check(str(result.decode()))
            except:
                print("Connection CLOSED BY CLIENT \n")
                break;
        socket.close()

    def _check(self,output):
        if output is "screenshot":
            print("Screenshot ESEGUITO \n")
        else:
            print(output)
```

Comment: could you try to replace `print(output)` with `print("'%s'"%output)` to see if there is any invisible char ?

Comment: Yes,no other chars...

Comment: And what about `len(output)` ? should be equal to 10 . Also I see that you are doing `result=socket.recv(1024)` twice, before the loop and in the loop. Are you sure that your method `_check` is called ? because there is also `print(result.decode())` that print the resut.

Comment: Yes the function works! I tested with a simple client in python and it send screenshot,and the function parse it correctly! The problem is the message with telnet,i think telnet adds other bytes to the message..

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible problem is that you are using `is` to compare string while you should be using `==`:

```
if output == "screenshot":
```

`==` is used to do « standard » comparison (i.e. equality of the value), the one you will use in most cases:

```
>>> 1 == 1
True
>>> [1, 2] == [1, 2]
True
```

`is` is used to check if the two variables point to the same object:

```
>>> [1, 2] is [1, 2]
False
>>> l1 = [1, 2]
>>> l2 = l2
>>> l1 is l2
True # Same object, if you update l1 you will also update l2
>>> l1[0] = 4
>>> l1, l2
([4, 2], [4, 2])
```

`is` may be misleading because in some case it is equivalent to standard `==`:

```
>>> 1 is 1
True
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s is 'hello'
True
>>> s = s.lower()
>>> s, s is 'hello'
('hello', False)
```

So, what going on here?

When you do `[1, 2]`, it creates a new list (new memory block) with value `1` and `2`, so if you do `[1, 2]` twice, two different lists are created, each one with a unique memory location, so `[1, 2] is [1, 2]` is `False`.

But, when you type `'hello'` you allocate a memory the first time, but then when type `'hello'` again, since it is a constant `string`, it points to the first one (to avoid duplication of identical memory blocks), so `s = 'hello' ; s is 'hello'` is `True`. Once you call `lower` on `s`, you create a new memory block, and even if this block contains the same data as `'hello'`, it is not at the same address, so `s.lower() is 'hello'` is False.

Comment: It's exactly the same i tried is but first i use the ==

Comment: So in OP case, he can't use `is` as `output` was not defined with the same constant string ?

Comment: @Hacketo Yes, in this case `is` works only if the two variables have been initizalied using the same constant string. But you should not use `is` to compare the value of two variables.

Comment: @Coogle In any way, your code wouldn't work without this answer, even if the problem is elsewhere.